# Change user annotation back to default blue dot in mapview

Tags: ios, objective-c, annotations, mapkit

I have created annotations on a mapview however i would like my user marker to return a flashing blue dot instead of a green pin. I cannot seem to figure out how to change the original user marker with the flashing blue dot. Here is my code.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DetailController.h"
#import "Annotation.h"

#import "City.h"

@interface ViewController (){
MKLocalSearch *localSearch;
MKLocalSearchResponse *results;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet DetailController *detailViewController;


@end
#define getDatalURL @"http://www.club-hop.com/apptest.php"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize mapView,jsonArray,citiesArray;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self retrieveData];
self.detailViewController = [[DetailController alloc] init];
[self.searchDisplayController setDelegate:self];
[self.ibSearchBar setDelegate:self];
//Zoom the map to current location.
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
[self.mapView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow];

City * cityObject;

// load external page into UIWebView
NSMutableArray * locations= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
Annotation * myAnn;

for(int u=0; u<citiesArray.count;u++){
    cityObject=[citiesArray objectAtIndex:u];

    myAnn=[[Annotation alloc]init];

    myAnn.city=cityObject;     // Store the city object on the annotation

    NSNumber *aLat= cityObject.Latitude;
    NSNumber *aLon= cityObject.Longitude;

    double lat = [aLat doubleValue];
    double lon = [aLon doubleValue];

    location.latitude= lat;
    location.longitude=lon;
    myAnn.coordinate = location;
    myAnn.title=cityObject.clubName;
    myAnn.subtitle=cityObject.cityName;

    [locations addObject:myAnn];}

[self.mapView addAnnotations:locations];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



//class methods
-(void) retrieveData{
NSURL * url= [NSURL URLWithString:getDatalURL];
NSData * data= [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
jsonArray= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

//setup cities array
citiesArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.count;i++){
    NSString * cID= [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString * cName= [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"cityName"];
    NSString * cCountry= [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"cityCountry"];
    NSString * cLine= [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"clubLine"];
    NSString * pri=[[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"price"];
    NSString * promo=[[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"promo"];
    NSString * clName= [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"clubName"];
    NSNumber * cLatitude= [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Latitude"];
    NSNumber * cLongitude= [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Longitude"];

    [citiesArray addObject:[[City alloc]initWithCityName:cName andCityCountry:cCountry andClubName:clName andClubLine:cLine andPrice:pri andPromo:promo andLatitude:cLatitude   andLongitude:cLongitude andCityId:cID]];

}

}


- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view         calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control

{   

UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                     bundle:nil];
self.detailViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Page2"];

Annotation *myAnnotation=(Annotation *)view.annotation;


self.detailViewController.city=myAnnotation.city;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];


}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id   <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
MKAnnotationView *pin=nil;
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotation class]])
{
    pin=(MKAnnotationView *)[mapView   dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"myAnnotation"];
    if (pin == nil)
    {
        pin=[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"myAnnotation"];
        pin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        pin.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"mappin.png"];
        pin.centerOffset=CGPointMake(0.0, pin.image.size.height/-2);
        pin.canShowCallout=YES;
    }
 }
 return pin;
}

@end
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you have posted the right code with the right question? This doesn't seem to be anything to do with a map view

Comment: wow youre right .h instead of .m..ill edit it now

Comment: Still nothing to do with a map view.  I have answered your question anyway

Comment: sorry i corrected the issue, not sure why it wasnt copying properly i should have noticed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this through your `viewForAnnotation` method in your `MKMapViewDelegate`.  If this method returns `nil` then the map view will use the default annotation view.  You can test the annotation to see if it is your subclass and then return a view or nil as appropriate.  Something like -

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *pin=nil;
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotation class]])
    {
        pin=(MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"myAnnotation"];
        if (pin == nil)
        {
            pin=[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"myAnnotation"];
            pin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            pin.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"mappin.png"];
            pin.centerOffset=CGPointMake(0.0, pin.image.size.height/-2);
            pin.canShowCallout=YES;   
        }
    }
    return pin;
}
```

Comment: something odd is happening with my copy and past i apologize. The solution you provided however does not show the annotations at the specified locations

Comment: You need to modify my code to ensure that you are testing for your Annotation class in the `isKindOfClass` test (I assumed it was called Annotation from your earlier question).  Most importantly you need to set up your annotation view in the `if (pin==nil) {...}` block - my code is what I used in one of my projects, but your image name etc will be different

Comment: I presumed you had existing code for `viewForAnnotation` otherwise you wouldn't have a different PIN view for the user's location